# React Native Flatlist onReachEnd does not load everything

Tags: react-native

So I have a FlatList where I have a pagination-system. This is my Flatlist:

```
<FlatList
  data={user}
  legacyImplementation={true}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
  onEndReached={() => {
    getMoreUsers()
  }}
  numColumns={2}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={refreshing}
      onRefresh={onRefresh}
    />
  }
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.userid}
  contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 150}}
  columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent:"space-between", paddingHorizontal: 20,}}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={{marginBottom: 20,}}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )} />
```

My problem is, that whenever new items are loading there are missing some of them. For example there are 90 users but it only shows 88 sometimes 87 :/ This is weird, isn't it? Did you ever had the same problem? My backend isn't the problem, because if I use PostMan there is no problem and I get everything as I wanted it.

This is my function to load more:

```
  const getMoreUsers = () => {
    fetch(pageNumber, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Token dcc997a9baf31d3f6e401e8e87eaa4bdb18c795a"},
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.next != null){
        setPageNumber(data.next)
        for(var i=0; i<data.results.length; i++){
          userList.push(data.results[i])
        }
        setUsersHook(userList)
      } else {
        "pass"
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

## Edit

I think this problem is caused, because the space of the Flatlist does not take everything of my screen, because I do have a Navigation Tabbar. Does anybody know, how to fix that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to change **onEndReachedThreshold**. For example to 1 or to 0.2. This worked for me.